# How should I understand such sentences without auxiliary verbs?

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality-in-context, minor-sentences

When I am reading [Philosophy and Simulation](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=TmbOBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false), I encountered the sentence:

> "the more numerous the sequences converging on a pattern the higher the likelihood that one of them will occur by chance."

But I could not understand what the sentence means. Could you paraphrase it for me? And could you explain how such sentences are grammatically correct because I have never seen such a sentence before?

> This spontaneity is explained both by the fact that the patterns are
>   small-patterns made out of a few live cells have a higher probability
>   of occurring than large ones-and by the fact that they can arise following several sequences of predecessor patterns: the more numerous the sequences converging on a pattern the higher the likelihood
>   that one of them will occur by chance.

Comment: Try to recognize the structure of your sentence (disregard the meaning for a moment) in the following proverb: “The more difficult the victory, the greater the happiness in winning.”

Comment: @user2684291 could you suggest me a link to learn grammer of such sentences?

Comment: Yes, [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives) and [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/Comparative-Correlatives.htm). The construction is quite easy, try to understand and memorize it through examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding where to pause is important for understanding a sentence like this.

> the more numerous the sequences converging on a pattern *(pause)* the
>   higher the likelihood that one of them will occur by chance.

In other words, when the sequences converging on a pattern are more numerous, that increases the likelihood that one of them will occur by chance.

Answer (score 1):

It means: if the sequences converge on a pattern more numerously, it will be more likely that one of them occur by chance.

These structures are called "Double Comparatives". These clauses have a conditional relationship, and the condition is always stated in the first clause.

For example:

> The more I read, the more I understand.

Its meaning is the same as the whole sentence: reading more about something helps me to understand it better.

You can also use "less" in one of your clauses and "more" in another one. I mean you don't need to use just "more" in both clauses. For example:

> The more I know her, the less I like her.